# Resource management when removing object from list

Tags: c#, resources

I'm trying to understand what is happening to an instance of an object when it is instantiated by using a List.Add(new Object) and then later List.Remove.

My question is - if I create an instance of a object and its only reference is in that list.  What happens when that item is removed from the list?  I've lost any reference I have to it because it's not in the list any more.  Does that mean it's gone from memory?

The example below is to just illustrate my question...I know this probably isn't how they make video games but it's how I can picture a non-abstract way to demonstrate what I'm asking.

```
class Enemy
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int level { get; set; }
    public int currentHP { get; set; }

    public Enemy(string name, int lvl, int HP)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.level = lvl;
        this.currentHP = HP;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //game starts
        List<Enemy> enemyList = new List<Enemy>();
        enemyList.Add(new Enemy("First enemy", 1, 150));
        enemyList.Add(new Enemy("Second enemy", 1, 150));
        enemyList.Add(new Enemy("Third enemy", 1, 150));

        //enemy 2 dies
        enemyList.RemoveAt(1);

        //some time passes
        //new enemy spawns
        enemyList.Add(new Enemy("Forth enemy", 1, 150));

        //game continues......
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you remove in item from the list, you loses the reference to it and can no longer access it. It stays in the memory until the GC collects it in its next run, but there is no way for you to access it.

In fact, if you know its exact memory address, you can access it by using hardware-level memory access functions. However, that's a nontrivial task and is only used in some security hacks (usually by performing a memory dump to find last used password(s)). It's not something you can consider to use in your own program.

If you want to remove it from the list, but still access it in the future, you can save a reference to it. For instance:

```
var deadEnemies = new List<Enemy>();
deadEnemies.Add(enemyList.Item[1]);
enemyList.RemoveAt(1);
```